# How to echo input text on button click in php

Tags: php, button, input

I am trying this code.

```
<form name="myWebForm" action="mailto:abhikulshrestha22@gmail.com"   method="post">
First: <input title="Please Enter Your First Name" id="first" name="first" type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="<?php echo first.text ?>"/>
</form>
```

As you can see,this we display a text input box and button.I want to display another text as echo below the button and input text box.

What should I do?

Please Help!

Comment: Your question is not very clear. The new field _As echo of WHAT_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language. This means, among other things, that (1) all PHP processing happens before the user sees your HTML and (2) what you are describing is impossible.

You have two options: (1) use JavaScript or, (2) if you need to do some server-side processing for some reason, use JavaScript to initiate an AJAX call. In any event, it's not clear what you mean when you say you want to "echo" something on a click event.

Also, please note that your syntax is completely incorrect. `first.text` would not be a valid PHP variable name, and you need a semicolon (`;`) at the end of your statement.